# Numerically solving a non-linear PDE

Tags: finite-difference, nonlinear-equations, parabolic-pde, diffusion

I have this non-linear partial differential equation.
$$
\frac{\partial C}{\partial t}=\left(\frac{\partial C}{\partial x}\right)^2+C\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial x^2}
$$

I want to use the finite difference method to solve it either with the implicit method or the Crank-Nicolson method, witch I have done with linear PDE's, but how is this done with non-linear PDE's

Comment: Where does this PDE come from? Do you have starting/boundary conditions to satisfy? It might be an idea to check that a unique solution exists before trying to find it.

Comment: It comes from the diffusion equation if D is linear depending on the concentration D = k*C(x,t),
in my case the boundary conditions is, C(0,t) = 14 and at C(xi,t)=2, where xi is a function of the concentration too, the initial conditions are C(x,0)=2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, the PDE can be rewritten instead as

$$\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}C\frac{\partial C}{\partial x}$$

or, by applying the product rule in reverse again, as

$$\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}C^2.$$

This equation is often referred to as the *porous medium equation* or the *slow diffusion* equation and it's got some fascinating properties.
The regular old linear heat equation

$$\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}D\frac{\partial C}{\partial x}$$

with conductivity $D$ has the property that disturbances propagate with infinite speed.
The slow diffusion equation, on the other hand, has a well-defined front that propagates with finite speed, which is very unusual.
This one of the simplest examples of a *free boundary problem*.

There are many ways to discretize nonlinear partial differential equations.
I'll describe a very blunt and simple approach that should hopefully get you started; it's based on using the first form of the slow diffusion equation that I wrote down.
The idea is to pretend like it's the linear diffusion equation, but to then take the diffusion coefficient to be the value of $C$ from the previous timestep.
Let
$$C_k^n = C(k\cdot\delta x, n\cdot\delta t)$$
be the values of the solution at time step $n$ and and spatial point $k$ and let $D_{k+\frac{1}{2}}$ be the value of the diffusion coefficient in the interval $[k\cdot\delta x, (k + 1)\delta x]$.
An implicit Euler discretization of the linear diffusion equation would be

$$\frac{C^{n + 1}_k - C^n_k}{\delta t} = \frac{D_{k + \frac{1}{2}}\frac{C^{n + 1}_{k + 1} - C^{n + 1}_k}{\delta x} - D_{k - \frac{1}{2}}\frac{C^{n + 1}_k - C^{n + 1}_{k - 1}}{\delta x}}{\delta x}.$$

You can then take the diffusion coefficient in each interval as

$$D_{k + \frac{1}{2}} = \frac{C_{k + 1}^n + C_k^n}{2}$$

using the concentration from the previous timestep to approximate the nonlinearity.

If you want a more accurate numerical solver, you might want to look into implementing [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization#Higher_dimensions).
That will be more involved though and it's better to try simple approaches first.

An important thing to account for is that parabolic PDE have a *maximum principle* -- a solution that is initially positive will stay positive.
The implicit Euler discretization has its own discrete maximum principle, whereas the Crank-Nicholson method does not.
Despite the fact that the Crank-Nicholson method is formally of higher order in $\delta t$, it could actually be much worse in practice for this reason.

Comment: I cant seem to get this to work for numerical solutions, since this procedure ends up with mixing the timesteps $$ C_{k}^{n} \cdot C_{k}^{n+1}$$